# Unable to publish file output in github pull request comment

Tags: git, api, jenkins, github, github-api

I am using Jenkins to trigger build as soon as pull request is raised on github. Once build is triggered, Jenkins starts performing some actions like build or scan etc. Later I am storing output of certain steps in a file (ex. publish.txt) and after successful build I would like to send this output to PR comment in github. I am able to publish normal comment using github api in PR but unable to send file output. How can I publish file output in PR comment.

Below is the command used to publish comment in PR.

```
curl -s -H "Authorization: token ${ACCESS_TOKEN}" \
-X POST -d '{"body": "Your Message to Comment"}' \
"https://api.github.com/repos/${REPO_OWNER}/${REPO_NAME}/issues/${PR_NUMBER}/comments"
```

Comment: Couldn't you use readFile to get the file content and then proceed the same way you do with normal comments?

Comment: I tied to do this in multiple ways but no luck. Could you please elaborate it little bit.

Comment: You are able to add a comment when you just have some text, right? So instead of trying to attach the file, you could just read the text out of it and proceed just with the text. For this you can use the readFile step which reads the contents of a file into a variable and then just pass the variable as comment text. For more information on the readFile step, see: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#readfile-read-file-from-workspace

Comment: @smelm: Thanks for your response but if I store file contents in the variable and try to publish in github then I get the following error "message": **"Problems parsing JSON"**
Below are the steps I used on linux machines :
`
content=$(cat file.txt)

curl -s -H "Authorization: token ${ACCESS_TOKEN}" \
-X POST -d "{"\body\": \"${content}\"}" \
"https://api.github.com/repos/${REPO_OWNER}/${REPO_NAME}/issues/${PR_NUMBER}/comments"
`

Comment: You could try printing out the {"\body\": \"${content}\"} part and pasting it into a json validator, to get a better error message

Comment: Hey Abhishek, any luck with this ? I'm trying same but facing same error as you.

Comment: I have recently published question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77105849/is-there-a-way-to-add-commentmultiple-line-to-github-pr-using-curl-command 
can you please answer it if you have a solution ?