# Is there a way to add comment(multiple-line) to GitHub PR using CURL command

Tags: json, github, curl, github-pages, github-api

I am trying put comment to GitHub PR using curl command but as my comment has multiple lines, it is failing to do so and throwing error:

```
"message": "Problems parsing JSON",
```

Here is how i'm trying it:
I have comment content available on fileA.

```
var1=`cat fileA`
curl -u $user:$token -X POST -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github+json' -d '{\"body\":\"$var1\"}' $URL
```

Tried with and without -H option but it doesn't really make any change.

Sample FileA:

```
PR Changes looks okay.
Changes can be merged to main branch.
Approved.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have got an answer:

By updating file content. Need to replace \n(newline) in file with 
 and then post it to GitHub Comment.

FileA(before):

```
PR Changes looks okay.
Changes can be merged to main branch.
Approved.
```

FileA(after):

```
PR Changes looks okay.<br>Changes can be merged to main branch.<br>Approved.
```

If you still face parsing issue try replacing "(double quotes) with '(single quotes)' - i faced this issue also.